# Set up permissions to serve files on OS X Parallels host via Apache2 on Ubuntu guest

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, osx-yosemite

I have a Yosemite machine where I work on PHP files that I'd like to serve up locally via the Ubuntu apache 2.4 guest running 14.04.

My Mac files can be served via Apache on OS X as I have set my apps folder in my home directory to set my uid to the staff group. But to isolate some server problems, I'd like to use the Apache installation on Ubuntu to serve up these files on the host OS X side but the permissions are not working. Reading up here and other places I ought to use the below command within Ubuntu to let Apache read and execute this data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/sam/Desktop/Parallels\ Shared\ Folders/Home/apps/umhef/
```

But ubuntu responds with Operation not permitted.

Of course I'm concerned about futzing up the permissions on OS X. What else can I share that would give insight into my environment? Or is this the wrong approach? thx, sam

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is done through a different path. The path I saw is not the appropriate path but it turns out to be on the guest Ubuntu side the following:

```
 /media/psf/the_shared_folder_I_set_up_in_parallels
```

Because of the work I did earlier in adding myself as in the www group earlier this works as expected. Many thanks to [this post](http://www.bluepiccadilly.com/2013/03/recreating-my-perfect-web-development-environment-using-parallels-vm-and-centos) I found after changing my search terms.